# Django template skip line every two iteration

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following html structure:

```
<div class="row>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

I am using pagination feature on Django to pass on 6 items per page.

How would I go about iterating over the paginator generated object list while wrapper each two box divs with row div?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `forloop.counter` in the template

```
{% for obj in obj_list %}
    {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:2 %}
    <div class="row">
    {% endif %}
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}

{% else %}
    Nothing to show
{% endfor %}
```

and if there are odd number of elements in the list, then it would not have a trailing `div`. I will let you figure out that scenario by yourself. (it is pretty simple)

Documentation for the [`forloop.counter0` can be found here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for)
Documentation for [`divisibleby` can be found here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby)

Comment: works but not working with infinite scrolling with waypoints infinite js

Answer (score 1):

I agree with karthikr's solution, but it doesn't print the `</div>` if you have 3, 5 items...

You have to add a `forloop.last` to handle that case:

```
{% for obj in obj_list %}
    {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:2 %}
    <div class="row">
    {% endif %}
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 or forloop.last %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}

{% else %}
    Nothing to show
{% endfor %}
```